# Docker compose file is invalid when downloading client data

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, azerothcore

I'm trying to install the Docker version of Azerothcore on Void Linux. I'm getting a docker error when I try and import the client data. I made sure docker was running and I searched around, but this error (for non Azerothcore isses) seems to require some editing of the shell scripts or something which is a bit beyond me. Any help would be appreciated. The error says:

```
>>>>> Running: docker-compose run --rm ac-build bash acore.sh client-data
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.abstract-bind: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.abstract-no-bind: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-authserver: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-authserver-prod: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-build: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-client-data-server: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-dev-server: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-tools: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-worldserver: 'profiles'
Unsupported config option for services.ac-worldserver-prod: 'profiles'
error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed with error: 1, however,
            it's not related to this Deno script directly. An error occurred within
            the script called by the command itself
          throw new Error(`Failed with error: ${status.code}, however,
                ^
    at Command.<anonymous> (file:///my-directory/azeroth-core/azerothcore-wotlk/apps/docker/docker-cmd.ts:290:17)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async file:///my-directory/azeroth-core/azerothcore-wotlk/apps/docker/docker-cmd.ts:240:5
```

Comment: Looks like your running an older version of docker. Can you post what docker and docker-compse versions your running?

Comment: `docker --version`
Docker version 20.10.6, build tag v20.10.6

`docker-compose --version`
docker-compose version 1.27.4, build unknown

Comment: ok, your docker version looks fine, but docker-compose is a bit older. You need to be on atleast 1.28.0. That is when they added support for service profiles.

Comment: I see. Well Void Linux doesn't have a more recent version of docker-compose on the package manager, so I guess I'll have to wait.

I tried manually installing as well, but Void doesn't have ACE at all so that's a no-go as well.

Answer (score 0):

My docker-compose version was out of date, so I uninstalled it with my package manager and then downloaded the newest version from this website:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Thanks to locus313 in the comments and ImXari on Discord, it seems to be working.